# php pagination of an array with previous and next tab

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

I have this array which contain around 1000 records. I want to display 20 array records per page.

```
  $list=array(
    array([title]=>"sony", [description]=>"camera"),
    array([title]=>"sony", [description]=>"mobiles"),
    array([title]=>"lenovo", [description]=>"laptop"),
    array([title]=>"lenovo", [description]=>"mobiles")
    );
```

I have used the following code for pagination. It is giving me a long row for pagination.
 Can someone help me to include previous and next code to my existing code so that my pagination will look good.

```
$page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) && $_REQUEST['page'] > 0 ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1;      

    function display($list, $page = 1) 
    {
    $start = ($page - 1) * 2;

    $list = array_slice($list, $start, 15);

    foreach ($list as $key => $val) {

        echo $val['title'] . '<br/>';
        echo $val['description'] . '<br/>';
        echo "<br>";
    }} $len = count($list);
    $pages = ceil($len / 2);
    if ($page > $pages or $page < 1)
     {
        echo 'page not found';
    }
    else
     {
        display($list, $page);
        for ($i = 1 ; $i <= $pages ; $i++)
        {
            $current = ($i == $page) ? TRUE : FALSE;
            if ($current) {
                echo '<b>' . $i . '</b>';
            }
            else
            {
                ?>

    <a href="http://localhost/flipkart-api/fkt_offer.php?offer=alloffers&page=<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></a>
    <?php
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with the data array from your question.

### The example

- The page size is assumed to be 2 (20 in your question).
- The size of the data array does not matter.
- The start parameter is provided (as in your example) thru a GET parameter *http://localhost/flipkart-api/fkt_offer.php?…start=index_or_page*. 
  This parameter is available in the script as *$_GET['start']*.
- The previous and next start indices are to be calculated ($start +/- $maxpage, etc.).
- To keep this example simple, I took the start index, not the page number, as parameter. But you also could use a page number and calculate the index, of course.
- For the reason of brevity I omitted error checking ("what if no more items", etc.).

Code:

```
    <?php
        // The data array
        $list=array(
            array('title'=>"sony",   'description'=>"camera"),
            array('title'=>"sony",   'description'=>"mobiles"),
            array('title'=>"lenovo", 'description'=>"laptop"),
            array('title'=>"lenovo", 'description'=>"mobiles")
        );

        // Evaluate URL
        $proto = ((isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"])) && (strtoupper($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) == 'ON')) ? "https://" : "http://";
        $hname = getenv("SERVER_NAME");
        $port = getenv("SERVER_PORT");
        if ( (($port==80)&&($proto=='http://')) || (($port==443)&&($proto=='https://')) ) { $port = ''; }
        $params = '';
        foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value) {
            if (strtolower($key)=='start') continue;
            $params .= (empty($params)) ? "$key=$value" : "&$key=$value";
        }
        $url = $proto . $hname . $port. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '?' . $params;

        // Page contents
        $last = count($list)-1;
        $start = (isset($_GET['start'])) ? intval($_GET['start']) : 0;
        if ($start<0) $start = 0; if ($start > $last) $start = $last;
        $maxpage = 2;
        echo "<p>Start index = $start</p>" . PHP_EOL;
        $curpage = 0;
        for($xi=$start; $xi<=$last; $xi++) {
            if ($curpage >= $maxpage) break;
            $curpage++;
            echo 'Entry ' . $curpage . 
                ':  ' . $list[$xi]['title'] . 
                ' - ' . $list[$xi]['description'] . 
                '<br />' . PHP_EOL;
        }

        // Navigation
        $prev = $start - $maxpage; if ($prev<0) $prev = 0;
        $next = ( ($start+$maxpage) > $last) ? $start : $start + $maxpage;
        $prev = ( ($start-$maxpage) < 0) ? 0 : $start - $maxpage;
        echo '<p><a href="'.$url.'&start='.$prev.'">Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo '<a href="'.$url.'&start='.$next.'">Next</a></p>';
    ?>
```

### Result (e.g)

```
    Start index = 2

    Entry 1: lenovo - laptop
    Entry 2: lenovo - mobiles

    Previous  Next
```

Comment: thanx for your quick response but i also want to add previous and next tag as pagination. This code is giving me direct all the array result at once. but i want when next tag is clicked that time display the other 2 result.

Comment: Ok, I modified my example. But, don't forget: SO is not a coding service. It's a place to get help and to learn!